# Visual C Multi-Threading (Please Help)?

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++

I have written a .NET program, using Windows form Application. 
My application is fairly simple.
Basically, I have two simple buttons on my form.
When the form is first loaded, I set up a global variable (bool run = true).

And my first button is essentially a very simple while loop.

`while(run)
{
 // do some code
}`

And what I want to do, is have the second button set the value of the boolean to false (bool run = false).

But, once I clicked the first button, I cannot even touch the second button!

I have read quite about this, and I think my solution is to use a multi-threading.
I have found some example codes on line for multi-threading, and I tried to incorporate those, but I don't know why I cannot get it to work. Once I click button #1, there is no way for me to be able to click button #2.

Comment: You can't do that on a UI thread.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Your code should respond to events, not *loop* until things to happen.

Comment: Well, with one button, I am writing to a Hard Drive (using fwrite), and usually depending on the transfer size and the size of the Hard Drive this process can take several minutes, which is fine, and I got that part working. But, I want the user to have the ability to stop the process if he wishes so. And, I don't know how to do it, since as long as that process (button #1) is going, I cannot touch anything else on the form. And, all I want is an ability to click on the second button, while the first one is still running.

Answer (score 0):

Your UI thread should not have any infinite or a wait-on-something - never! You must not block the UI for anything (other than simple calculations, validations, user confirmation etc). You should make a thread for performing length task, and let that thread communicate to UI thread using **asynchronous** (or synchronous, if you prefer) communication.

On native Windows GUI application, you can use `PostMessage` (*async*), or `SendMessage` (*sync*). For .NET GUI applications, you can use `Control.BeginInvoke` (*async*), or `Control.Invoke` (*sync*).

Please [read this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43994/The-Practical-Guide-to-Multithreading-Part-1) on how this is done.